# ELK: Kibana graph chart & elastic-search mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I'd like to ask for advice about Kibana's graph visualization & ElasticSearch mapping with [`join` types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/mapping-types.html).

I am having different entities, let say pets (let's call them major entities) and their owners (minor entity).

I am inserting pets in `PETS` index and put owners in separate index of `OWNERS`. So some pets have a property that can be connected/join with the following (only one) owner.

Like this:

pets

```
{ 
  id: 1,
  name: 'Pikacho',
  ownerId: 1
}
```

owner

```
{ 
  id: 1,
  name: 'Rachel',
  petId: 1
}
```

> *Actually I am free to use every structure I want, even nested owner documents inside every pet. The real question is how to achieve the best case for graph data*

Owners are really a separate entity and I don't need them in the business logic of my app, but sometimes, as a user I'd like to check in Kibana's UI via graph chart how many pets have one owner and so on.

[image]

So my question is: Are there any restrictions on data inserting (with`.index` method) via ElasticSearch driver for node.js, if I'd like to build a [graph chart](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-graph.html)?

- Should I create `index` via `.create` index and mark every field with correct [`mapping`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/mapping-types.html) or I can just write them as usual in Elastic and connect necessary field inside Kibana by the result?
- How to use the `join` relation correctly in this case if I have to use it for graph charts and should I use them at all?
- Should I have two different indexes for performable graph chats, or it's better to have a document-oriented way with:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Pikachoo',
  owner: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Rachel'
  }
}
```

My Elastic & Kibana versions are 7.16+ (current) I'll be glad to have any example provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing about the [Graph application](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-graph.html) in Kibana and the underlying [Graph API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/graph-explore-api.html) is that they don't require you to index your data in any specific way, which means they don't leverage `join` fields or parent-child or nested relationships at all.

The only thing that Graph uses to create connections are common values between documents, and based on those, it can create a network of related terms in the index.

It's very easy to start exploring your data with Graph.

1. Create an index pattern in Kibana that spans both indexes `pets` and `owners`
2. Open the Graph application, select the index pattern you just created
3. Select the two fields `petName` and `ownerId`
4. Click "Graph" and you'll start seeing connections between your data. The label of the vertices will be the pet/owner IDs and the vertices will be connected

Here is an example of how it could look like based on your data:

[image: owner / pet graph]